# enable target membership issue on .m file

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

when i enable keyboard target extension on .m file then this controller give errors like  Use of undeclared identifier. i am creating custom keyboard extension on swift and i want add objective c class on keyboard target extension like

[image]

when i disable custom keyboard like this

[image]

then app work proper but i required to enable extension target so, how can i solve this issue.

i already check bridging file and build phase in compile resource on both extension and host app target.

Thanks

Comment: Have you add .m file Custom Keyboard target?

Comment: yes i add but that time show error in .m file like undeclared identifier without add .m file on custom keyboard proper run the project. i want create object of custom keyboard class without add target its not possible to create object of keyboard controller class.

Comment: without add target create an object on mainView controller then show this type of error *   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController", referenced from:
 *